# Can I use a service which is used by the imported component?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've started developing via Angular2 and I really liked it. But today I faced with such a problem: I have a reusable component of alerts which uses it's own service with business logic in it.

Can I use the same service to put data for tests in another component but importing my reusable component in it? Is it okay? 
Will my reusable component see the data in the service which is imported into service in such a way?

Thank you for your answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what do you want :

- If you want the service to be the same(singleton) you need to inject the service in a root component or in the Bootstrap, which should be fine.
- If you want a service for the alerts component and with different data for another component, just inject the service in both, which also should be fine.
  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html